# How to remove or disable previously selected values in datepickers or other input?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When user selects values for datepickers, the browser remembers previous entries if I double click the input field. Is there any way to disable that for some (not all) input fields?

[image: datepicker]

Form input:

```
= form.input_field :date, :id => "date1"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values that are appearing there are actually suggestions for autocompletion that the browser has saved for you.

To disable it, you just need to set `autocomplete="off"` in your form tag.

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...
```

Source: [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)